# How can I list an output of files and let the user select them

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I have to do a ***bash script*** that shows disk usage and free space and if a certain point is set as an argument of that script, allow user to select files that are greater than 10MB and delete them or pack and move them somewhere else and check if that point is satisfied and if not repeat that action.
So far for listing files from all of **/home/$USER** that are over 10MB i got this command line:

```
find . -size +10M -exec ls -Rla --block-size=M -I ".*" {} \+ | sort -n | awk '{print "PERM: " $1 " SIZE: " $5 " PATH: " $8}'
```

I got some serious issues with it like **awk** is not sorting out files with **spaces** in their paths and if files that doesn't have a hour value are not shown neither because columns doesn't match. I don't know why **-I ".*"** statement is not working too.

So my question "Is it possible to do that in one script - like generating a list of files over 10MB and letting user to chose from them?"

Comment: `find . -size +10M -exec ls -Rla --block-size=M -I ".*" {} \+` 1. Remove `ls`. [Do not parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead). 2. Use `find ... -printf` to print the filename and size.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please post how this command would look like without **ls** because I'm a freshman at bash and I know that find is really extensive command :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paths are allowed to have **any characters** except zero byte. The only possible way to work safely with any files is to use zero separated streams. Note that you have to have GNU tools then as they support various `-z`/`-0` options, or use a different programming language. A common trick is to put *before the filename* stuff that will have known format, and then put the filename. That way you can extract them with like a regex (or with `cut -d' ' -f2-`).

```
find . -type f -size +10M -printf '%s %p\0' |
sort -z -n -k1 |
awk -v RS="\0" '
{
     # remove everything after the first space
     size = $0; gsub(/ .*$/, "", size)
     # remove everythign before the first space
     file = $0; gsub(/^[^ ]* /, "", file)
     print "SIZE: " size " PATH: " file
}'
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much! It's way to complicated for me at this moment :D How can I edit it so this **find** is excluding important files like .config directory and hidden files?

Comment: `'!' -name '.config' '!' -name '.*'`

Comment: And where do I put that? Because I added it after **-size +10M** and it doesn't seem to sort it out and doesn't give any error of syntax neither. By the way is there a possibility to present the size value in MB format?